# Laravel 5 - Old Data on multiple checkboxes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a lot of checkboxes which take the following form in my template

```
<div class="col-md-6 checkbox checkbox-danger">
    {!! Form::checkbox('testingOptions[]', 'Checkbox A', null, ['class' => 'styled', 'id' => 'checkbox1']) !!}
    <label for="checkbox1">
        Checkbox A
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 checkbox checkbox-danger">
    {!! Form::checkbox('testingOptions[]', 'Checkbox B', null, ['class' => 'styled', 'id' => 'checkbox2']) !!}
    <label for="checkbox2">
        Checkbox B
    </label>
</div>
```

So selected options are saved to testingOptions[].

In my controller, I get the input, and then basically implode all of the choices into a single string

```
$testingOptions = Input::get('testingOptions');
$testingOptions = implode('&&&', $testingOptions);
```

In my database, I end up with something like this

```
Checkbox A&&&Checkbox B
```

This is all fine.  For my edit controller, I am doing the following

```
$selectedOptions = $project->something->testing;
if($selectedOptions != "") {
    $selectedOptions = explode('&&&', $selectedOptions);
    return View::make('something.edit', compact('project', 'selectedOptions'));
}
```

With that done, in my edit template, if I output selectedOptions I have something like this

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Checkbox A"
  1 => "Checkbox B"
]
```

So knowing that on my edit page i have

```
<div class="col-md-6 checkbox checkbox-danger">
    {!! Form::checkbox('testingOptions[]', 'Checkbox A', null, ['class' => 'styled', 'id' => 'checkbox1']) !!}
    <label for="checkbox1">
        Checkbox A
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 checkbox checkbox-danger">
    {!! Form::checkbox('testingOptions[]', 'Checkbox B', null, ['class' => 'styled', 'id' => 'checkbox2']) !!}
    <label for="checkbox2">
        Checkbox B
    </label>
</div>
```

Is there any way to use the variable array of previously selected options to pre-select their matches within my form?

Thanks

Comment: So like this: `{{ old('NAME_OF_INPUT') }}`

Comment: Check this link out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#old-input

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by doing

```
{!! Form::checkbox('testingOptions[]', 'Checkbox A', in_array('Checkbox A', $testingOptions), ['class' => 'styled', 'id' => 'checkbox1']) !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('testingOptions[]', 'Checkbox B', in_array('Checkbox B', $testingOptions), ['class' => 'styled', 'id' => 'checkbox1']) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, I'd use laravel's built in [`old()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#old-input) function:

```
{{ old('username') }}
```

Comment: I understand using old, but I dont think this will work in my case.  My checkboxes are serialized to the database, and it is an array I am passing my form

Comment: `old` simply saves the data that is passed to the server from the previous request from the client.